# MVC: Visual Studio Publish Web dialog cannot find my application's Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, deployment, publishing

I am using [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to publish my *ASP.NET MVC 4* application using *Visual Studio 2010* on *IIS 7.5* running on a *64-bit Windows 7 Professional* machine.

When I click the **Publish** button on the wizard after entering the values, it reports a single error that reads:

```
Copying file Views\Shared\Error.cshtml 
to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml failed. 
Could not find file 'Views\Shared\Error.cshtml'.
```

I looked into the target folder where the wizard dumps the necessary files that will be needed to deploy the application. It turns out that the folder had the Views folder which had only the _ViewStart.cshtml of the root Views folder, but no other View. My application has at least 20 views, perhaps more.

Comment: make sure the "Build Action" of the view files is set to "Content" and not something else (like None).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I learnt something new. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that it was my fault. The local copy of my project had the file Error.cshtml in the Views\Shared folder. However, the TFS copy of the project file did not. Apparently, the file had been excluded from the project at some stage.

I excluded the file from my project locally and ran the build and it worked.

Comment: +1 because this just helped me out massively. seems a little silly that i had to exclude one of my view files locally, but this saved a few hours of frustration!

Comment: Thank you. I am glad it helped. Your comment just reminded me that I'd forgotten to mark my answer as the right one. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that the file was in the solution but didn't actually exist on the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem occurred when I moved a file (via explorer) from the shared folder to another folder.

I added the file in visual studio, but did not "delete" the file from the shared folder (as far as visual studio was concerned).

For some reason, visual studio did not put a little flag or warning sign to tell me the expected file was missing (even after a refresh), so I didn't notice (although trying to open the missing file revealed the problem).

The error message is clear, and self explanatory. I just couldn't understand it for some reason.